# How to concat columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation, multiple-columns

PostgreSQL 15.0
I want to make a query that concats two different columns into one.

Desired outcome I showed in the exapmle (it's not a real one but it would be useful to understand on this example).

I've used CONCAT but it does't create new column, just concatenation.
How do I get:

```
id       Col1        Col2
1        foo          10
2        bar          42
3        baz          14
```

to

```
id           NewColumn
1             foo: 10
2             bar: 42
3             baz: 14
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and the SQL query you tried.

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to permanently and physically add a new column to the table, or if you just want a query that returns the concatenated values. If you really want to add a new column then the question is: why? That seems quite unnecessary

Comment: Don't you just need CONCAT(col1, ': ', col2)? For example SELECT id, col1, col2,
CONCAT(col1, ': ', col2) AS NewColumn
FROM yourtable

Comment: `SELECT col1||':'||col2 AS NewColumn FROM table`

Comment: `||` is the SQL standard concatenation operator.

Comment: Yes, of course you can also just use || rather than CONCAT. But even with CONCAT, I don't see the problem. Seems like OP missed to tell an important information ;)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create table t (id int, col1 text, col2 int);

insert into t values
    (1, 'foo', 10),
    (2, 'bar', 42), 
    (2, 'baz', 14), 
    (2, null, 14),
    (2, 'wow', null);
    
   select id, coalesce(col1, '') || ': ' || coalesce(col2::text, '') AS NewColumn FROM t
```

check the live demo here
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sNANpwdUPdJfUaSQ77MQUM/1

and read docs here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

And do not forget about null values

But if you want to create a really new column in the table as a result of concatenation:

```sql
alter table t 
    add column NewColumn text 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        coalesce(col1, '') || ': ' || coalesce(col2::text, '')
    ) STORED;

select id, NewColumn FROM t
```

Check the live demo here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sNANpwdUPdJfUaSQ77MQUM/2

And documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

Comment: If you use `concat()` or `concat_ws()` then NULL values will be handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below statement,

`select id, Col1||': '||Col2 as NewColumn from table_name;`

In order to get Col1 and Col2 as well, you can use below,

`select id, Col1, Col2, Col1||': '||Col2 as NewColumn from table_name;`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Name, CONCAT(col1, " ", col2) AS NewColumn FROM Data;
```

this code concat the 2 column in table, see more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp)

Comment: That's a bad variation of the queries already mentioned in comments because it just misses the ":". Now you could go and add this, but this would still be a duplicate. Better let OP clarify their question.

Comment: String constants need to use `'` in SQL. The double quotes (`"`) are for identifiers (e.g. column names)